# Application with multiple windows as instances of a class, C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, object, instance

I wrote an application. There is a **class named APP**, with handle to the window, and message loop inside it, and all this stuff.

It is intended to "run" some objects of this class, each with its own window based on a set of variables necessary for a standard window.

Message loop is allowed for public use, it is ran by RunMessageLoop method.
int nCmdShow - of course, it is used to tell how to display a window.

Now, when i create some objects like this:

```
vector <APP *> App;
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    App.push_back(&APP(nCmdShow))
    App[i]->RunMessageLoop();
}
```

program waits for each message loop to end before it starts another.

I figured out to make it this way:

```
vector <APP *> App;
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    App.push_back(&APP(nCmdShow))
}
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    App[i]->RunMessageLoop();
}
```

When i know how many windows I want at startup to be run, it seems to be ok.

But I don't know how to create new windows dynamically, with complete independence of other windows. It should invoke message loops and immediately return to WinMain() without ending message loops.

I thought about multi-threaded app, each thread per one instance of an APP class. But don't know how to build multithreaded app, though.

Any ideas for a possible solution?

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour. When you do this: `App.push_back(&APP(nCmdShow))` you are storing pointers to temporary objects that get immediately destroyed.

Comment: Well, it seems to me that it is not destroyed, since I can see window, and it is responding to messages. If it is coded improperly, please provide some advices for me, if you can.

Comment: @bercik "Undefined behaviour" can *seem* like it's working, and haunt you for weeks at a later time when its undefined-ness is exposed for some reason. I'm surprised that `&APP(nCmdShow)` even compiles. You should use `new`, not `&` there.

Comment: I know only basis of pointer usage; I am not skilled with operator new. How would it look in code?

Comment: When you create an object without using `new`, you create it on the stack. Therefor once the function that you created the `APP`'s in returns, the `APP`'s are destroyed, thus rendering the pointers to the `APP`'s stored in your vector invalid. Use `App.push_back(new APP(nCmdShow))` and the `APP` will be stored in dynamic memory, keeping it from being destroyed, then the pointers will be valid. BTW, the windows will still appear regardless of whether you have made invalid pointers to them.

Comment: @bercik Also, what is the point of each window having its own message loop? An application usually has just one message loop, which routes every message that the application gets to the correct window procedure that the message belongs to.

Comment: Ok thanks. It is really awesome being served with help for free:) Any advices to my main question?

Comment: Well, I want to create an application with multiple windows, each with its own message loop. Is this possible? I mean, I want to run one app, then show many windows, for example clients for testing server. I do not want to run them hundred times by myself

Comment: You can make an application with multiple windows, but it should only have one message loop. When the message loop gets a message, it sends it to the procedure (LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM)) of the window that the message belongs to. Think of the message loop as the mail man, when the mail man gets mail, he checks to see who it belongs to, then sends it to that person. Think of the windows procedure as the person getting the mail. The person reads the mail that belongs to them, and does something in response to what they have just read.

Comment: So all you need to do is create the windows and make sure you have given them different procedures (MyWindow1(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM) for Wnd1, MyWindow2(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM) for Wnd2) so that they process their own message independent of each-other.

Comment: Well, I know what you mean, but what i want is more: each window should have its own WndProc. Putta Khunchalee posted an answer below, I will try to make it his way, and see if it really makes me satisfied. For now, multi-threaded app seems to be the only solution.

Comment: @bercik Ah, I see what you mean. You want for each window to dynamically have its own procedure that is a member-function of the window object instead of having to define individual free-function procedures for each window. IMO, the multi-threaded approach seems like overkill, and it is most definitely not the only solution, or even the best. You should check out my answer before trying that approach, it will probably save you some time and headaches.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you are trying to do now, I have achieved this in my application framework called Lucid (it is still a work in progress). For the sake of the answer, your window class will be called `Window` instead of `APP`.

This is done by passing a global procedure to every window you create. All windows share this same procedure. Every time any window gets a message, that message is sent to the global procedure, the global procedure checks if the `HWND` belongs to a `Window` that you created, and if it does, sends the message to that `Window`s' procedure. Here's an overview of how this works.

```
class Window
{
public:
    // The contents of this function can vary from window to window
    // provided that you make a subclass and override this method.
    virtual LRESULT procedure(HWND wnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp);

    // When you create a Window object, add a pointer to it in this map.
    // Eg. if (this->hwnd != NULL) createdWindows[this->hwnd] = this;
    static map<HWND, Window*> createdWindows;

    // When you create a window, make this its procedure.
    static LRESULT CALLBACK routeMessage(HWND wnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
    {
        if (createdWindows.find(wnd) != createdWindows.end()) {
            // Message belongs to one of our 'Window' objects.
            // Pass the message to that window and return the result.
            return createdWindows[wnd]->procedure(wnd, msg, wp, lp);
        } else {
            // It seems you made 'routeMessage' the procedure
            // of a window that doesn't belong in the map. Go ahead
            // and process the message in the default manner.
            return DefWindowProc(wnd, msg, wp, lp);
        }
    }
};
```

Now you will only need a single message loop and a single thread. I have a test project using Lucid that creates 2 windows with different procedures on a single thread with a single message loop:

```
#include "Lucid.h"
using namespace Lucid;

void sayBye(MessageEventArgs& e)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Goodbye!", "Form 2", MB_OK);
    e.handled = true;
}    

void Program::onStart()
{
    Form* myForm1 = new Form("Hello World!");
    myForm1->show();

    Form* myForm2 = new Form("Hello World!");
    myForm2->addMessageHandler(WM_CLOSE, sayBye);
    myForm2->show();

    // This Program::onStart() function is called
    // immediately before the single message loop is entered.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is also very interesting. I will try it and post my thoughts about it.

Answer (score 0):

Create the threads with `_beginthreadex` equal to the number of window you need to run. Then, run message loop in the thread procedure and wait until all thread has been terminated with `WaitForMultipleObjects`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll try to implement it and see results, then i give you feedback.